# Multiple histogram graphs with Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Graphing with matplotlib I get this 4 histograms model:
[image: 4 Histograms]

Using Seaborn I am getting the exact graph I need but I cannot replicate it to get 4 at a time:
[image: Seaborn]

I want to get 4 of the seaborn graphs (image 2) in the format of the image 1 (4 at a time with the calculations I made with seaborn).

My seaborn code is the following:

```
import os
import re  
import time
import ipdb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'camel_product_list.csv')

gapminder = pd.read_csv(path_file)
print(gapminder.head())
df = gapminder
sns.distplot(df['average_histogram_ssim'], hist=True, kde = False, label='All values')
df = gapminder[gapminder.color == 'green']
# sns.distplot(df['lifeExp'], hist = True, kde = True, label='Only Matches')
sns.distplot(df['average_histogram_ssim'], hist_kws={"histtype": "step", 
                            "linewidth": 3,
                            "alpha": 1, "color": "b"} , 
                            kde = False, label='Only Matches')
# Plot formatting
plt.legend(prop={'size': 12})
plt.title('ratio_image SSIM')
plt.xlabel('Data Range')
plt.ylabel('Density') 
plt.show()
```

The names of the columns of the dataframe are:

```
'ratio_text','ratio_image', 'ratio_hist', 'ratio_sub', 'color'
```

I'm using the color column as a filter.

How can I get the 4 seaborn plots for **ratio_text','ratio_image', 'ratio_hist', 'ratio_sub',** filtered by all colors and green color?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you are having trouble. Where do these colors come into play?

Answer (score 5):

First define your grid of subplots and assign its four axes to an array `ax`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

Now you can pass the axes you want to plot on to the seaborn plotting function with the `ax` keyword argument, e.g. for the first plot:

```py
sns.distplot(df['average_histogram_ssim'], hist=True, kde=False, label='All values', 
             ax=ax[0, 0])
```

Same with `ax=ax[0, 1]` for the upper right plots, and so on.

Comment: is there no way to do this in a seaborn one-liner? :\